# jndi.properties - how to set it?

Tags: java, properties, log4j, jndi

Is there any way to set `jndi.properties` file or to set topic in code?
For now I put this file into `src` folder, bit I really need to set this configuration in source code.

`jdni.properties:`

```
topic.logTopic=logTopic
```

Is there any way similar to e.g.

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("path")
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the properties in the environment used to create the InitialContext.

Comment: It is difficult to understand, could you please explain in more details?

Comment: I tried   `Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
  env.put(Context.???, 
   "logTopic");
  Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);` but I don't know how to set topic

Comment: @trebuchet It is easy to understand. You have a property name and a property value. The name is the first argument, the value is the second argument.

Comment: True, the rule is easy, but I still cannot configure it. `Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
   env.put("topic.logTopic", "logTopic");
   Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);` doesn't work.

Comment: @trebuchet That suggests that putting it into jndi.properties wouldn't work either.